# python requests for load more data

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

i want to scrap product images from https://society6.com/art/i-already-want-to-take-a-nap-tomorrow-pink of each product >

step=1 first i go in div', class_='card_card__l44w (which is having each product link)
step=2 then parse the href of each product >

but its getting back only first 15 product link inspite of all 44

==============================
second thing is when i parse each product link and then grab json from there `['product']['response']['product']['data']['attributes']['media_map']`
after media_map key there are many other keys like b , c , d , e , f , g (all having src: in it with the image link i only want to parse .jpg image from every key)
below is my code

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


baseurl = 'https://society6.com/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
    }

r = requests.get('https://society6.com/art/flamingo-cone501586', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
productslist = soup.find_all('div', class_='card_card__l44w')
productlinks = []
for item in productslist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
newlist = []
for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')[9].text.strip()[24:]
    data = json.loads(scripts)
    url = data['product']['response']['product']['data']['attributes']['media_map']
    detail = {
        'links' : url
        }
    newlist.append(detail)
    print('saving')
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
df.to_csv('haja.csv')`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdhXP.png
```

Comment: It is because Python can only check 15 products, but not `View All Products` one.

Answer (score 0):

All the information is loaded at first visit and all 66 products are stored in `window.__INITIAL_STATE`.
If you scroll almost to the end of the file you can see it.

You can use that to parse the information.

```
import re
import json

data = json.loads((soup
                   .find("script", text=re.compile("^window.__INITIAL_STATE"))
                   .text
                   .replace("</script>", "")
                   .replace("window.__INITIAL_STATE = ", "")))

products = data["designDetails"]["response"]["designDetails"]["data"]["products"]
```

products is a list with 66 items. Example:

```
 {'sku': 's6-7120491p92a240v826', 
 'retail_price': 29, 
 'discount_price': 24.65, 
 'image_url': 'https://ctl.s6img.com/society6/img/yF7u4l5D3MODQBBerUQBHdYsfN8/h_264,w_264/acrylic-boxes/small/top/~artwork,fw_1087,fh_1087,fx_-401,fy_-401,iw_1889,ih_1889/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/misc/f7916751f46d4d9c9fb7f6fe4e5d5729/~~/flamingo-cone501586-acrylic-boxes.jpg', 
 'product_type': {'id': 92, 
                  'title': 'Acrylic Box', 
                  'slug': 'acrylic-box', 
                  'slug_plural': 'acrylic-boxes'}, 
 'department': {'id': 83, 
                'title': 'Office'}, 
 'sort': 0}
```

Comment: yes Thanks , but image i got there is low resolution so i have to go inside of each products link and grab high resolution image so i used `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
page = soup/find('div', class_='bottomRow_productsWithThisDesignGrid_28Phq')
productslist = soup.find_all('div', class_='card_card__l44w')
productlinks = []
for item in productslist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])`

Comment: we i go in each product this only give me first 15 product data inspite of all 66 . second if you can help me out , if i go in each product and then grab json from there and then `['product']['response']['product']['data']['attributes']['media_map']` there are many keys like b , c , d , e , f , g , h , that all having src: then xl or xxl ( having webp and jpg image link) i only want to grab xxl or xl .jpg

Comment: Can you post that as an edit to your question? I cant recreate it (empty list), but maybe I am doing something different. Just give me an hint on how to access the media_map

Comment: yes i edited my question so you can understand,Thanks

Comment: have to checked